# What type of rock is a "slide-rock"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What type of rock is a "slide-rock"?

> In those days we had never heard of passing up a chance to kill a wolf. In a second we were pumping lead into the pack, but with more excitement than accuracy: how to aim a steep downhill shot is always confusing. When our rifles were empty, the old wolf was down, and a pup was dragging a leg into impassable **slide-rocks**.

Context: [*Thinking Like a Mountain* By Aldo Leopold](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Comment: My guess would be a field of broken shale-like rock, sometimes seen at the edge of an embankment, or near a stream.  The rock can be nearly impossible for humans to walk on because it shifts so easily underfoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merriam-Webster defines [slide-rock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slide%E2%80%93rock) as:

> rock shards in talus,

where [talus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talus) is defined as:

> 1:  a slope formed especially by an accumulation of rock debris
>
> 2:  rock debris at the base of a cliff

Thus, slide-rock is usually referring to the rock debris that falls of a cliff face, or that results from a landslide.